# Assigning a Route53 DNS programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have the following code which works fine provided I have an A record for ***`serverBase.mydomain.net`*** which points to  IP ***`10.20.30.40`***
But if I want to create an A record serverProxy which points to the IP (Swap in the commented out line), but it gives the error:

> "Tried to create an alias that targets 10.20.30.40., type A in zone
>   ********* , but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone"

I can do this manually so it is something in the code that is incorrect ?

```
    String subDomainName = "serverProxy.mydomain.net";
    String zoneId = "**********";
    //String target = "serverBase.mydomain.net";
    String target = "10.20.30.40";

    AmazonRoute53Client client = getAmazonRoute53Client();
    List<Change> changes = new ArrayList<Change>();
    List<ResourceRecord> recourceRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet(subDomainName+".",RRType.A);

    //AliasTarget alias = new AliasTarget(zoneId, target);
    //alias.setEvaluateTargetHealth(false);
    //resourceRecordSet.setAliasTarget(alias);

    changes.add(new Change( ChangeAction.CREATE, resourceRecordSet));
    ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch(changes);

    try {
        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest changeResourceRecordSetsRequest = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest(zoneId, changeBatch);
        client.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsRequest);
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ALIAS` record set can only point to a DNS name. It cannot point directly to an IP address.

If you want to create a record that points to an IP address, then you want to create an `A` record.

Comment: It is an A record that I am trying to create.  I specify this with  ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet(subDomainName+".",RRType.A);   But it doesn't work :(

Comment: But you are setting an `AliasTarget` on the record.

Comment: I see. That may be the problem as the error talks about the Alias target.  Will try it tomorrow and select as answer if it works.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have tried the code with the Alias Target code removed and pointing to an IP address but now the error is that the request is invalid.  Looking at the code I don't see how do I configure the RecordResourceSet instance with the IP I want the A Record to point to?  There is only  a setAliasTarget methon on the RecordResourceSet instance

Comment: Got it working.  For anyone that might find this question useful I added  my working code in seperate answer. Thanks @ Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
    String zoneId = "myzoneID";
    String cname = "myserver.mydomain.net";

    AmazonRoute53Client client = getAmazonRoute53Client();
    List<Change> changes = new ArrayList<>();

    Change change = new Change()
            .withAction(ChangeAction.CREATE)
            .withResourceRecordSet(new ResourceRecordSet()
                    .withType(RRType.CNAME)
                    .withName( cname )
                    .withTTL(300L)
                    .withResourceRecords(new ResourceRecord( "10.20.30.40" )));

    changes.add( change );
    ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch(changes);
    try {
        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest changeResourceRecordSetsRequest = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest(zoneId, changeBatch);
        client.changeResourceRecordSets(changeResourceRecordSetsRequest);
        logback.info( "DNS Record " + cname +  " created");
    }
    catch( InvalidChangeBatchException icbe )
    {
        String error = icbe.getMessage();
        if( error.contains("already exists" ))
        {
            logback.info( "DNS Record already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            throw icbe;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally, you would create a `CNAME` referring to a DNS name (like an `ALIAS`). For IPs, they should be `A` records.